# Limits for sequences: Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n^2 - 3n + 5}{9 - n^2} = -2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n^2 - 3n + 5}{9 - n^2} = -2$$

Note, this is a sequence.

I know that  a sequence $(c_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to a finite value L if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N>0$ so that for all $n$ it holds that:
$$n > N \implies |c_n - L| < \epsilon$$.

I've learnt this in school: $|c_n - L| < \epsilon$ is the distance between each sequence term and the epsilon-value. If we can write $n$ in terms of epsilon, then for any epsilon, we can easily 'choose' an N-value, so that the implication above holds.

I'm afraid I haven't gotten further than this... :

$$\left|\frac{2n^2 - 3n + 5}{9 - n^2} - (-2)\right| < \epsilon \iff \left|\frac{23 - 3n}{9 - n^2}\right| < \epsilon$$

I just can't seem to reduce $n$ in a way that would help me solve this inequality...
I don't know if there is some algebraic trick that is going over my head or if there is some "theoretical trick" which I could use to simplify. Please, a hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Advice: Don't start a question with TLDR.

Comment: Here's a general strategy:  Let $f(x) = \frac{2x^2-3x+5}{9 - x^2}$, so that $f(n) = c_n$ when $n = 1 , 2, 3, \dots$.  Note that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -2$, by say, L'Hopital's Rule, or by dividing top and bottom by $x^2$ (just like in Doug's answer below).  If $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$, then $lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = L$ too.  Note that this implication only goes one way.  If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = L$, but the converse is false in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n^2 - 3n + 5}{9 - n^2} = -2$

Divide to and bottom by $n^2$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 - \frac {3}n + \frac {5}{n^2}}{- 1 + \frac {9}{n^2}} = -2$

And when $n$ gets to be large the $\frac {1}n$ terms become small.  The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is not necessry.

But if that is the direction you want to go.

There exists an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $\left|\frac {3n-23}{n^2-9}\right| < \epsilon$

let $N = \max (\frac {3}{\epsilon},4)$

Comment: Great thanks! One more question - when should I use 'the quick way' and when should I use epsilon-delta? I don't _exactly_ understand what 'proving a limit' means...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove that $\frac{23-3n}{9-n^2}\to 0$.

Comment: I understand that this proves that the sequence converges, but how will the condition n > N be met? I was taught that we have to write n in terms of epsilon so that for any given epsilon, it would be simple to determine N.

Comment: Should I use the comparison theorem to prove that the expression converges and then use my comparison to get epsilon in terms of n?

Answer (score 1):

You want so show that  $$\left|\frac{23 - 3n}{9 - n^2}\right| < \epsilon$$  First when $n$ is large enough ($n>8$) $$\left|\frac{23 - 3n}{9 - n^2}\right| =\frac{3n-23}{n^2-9}<\frac{3n}{n^2-9}
$$
Also, if $n$ is this large, we have $n^2-9>\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$ so $$\frac{3n}{n^2-9}<\frac{12n}{n^2}=\frac{12}{n}$$

Therefore, it's enough to take $$n > \max\left(8,\frac{12}{\epsilon}\right)$$

**NOTE**

I don't recommend doing it this way.  You should just show the fraction goes to $0$ which guarantees the existence of such an $N$.  Doing it this way is more tedious, no more rigorous, and in my view, adds nothing to understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If we take $n > 3+\frac6\varepsilon$ we have $ \frac{3}{n-3} < \frac{\varepsilon}2$, and if we take $n > \sqrt{\frac{28}\varepsilon + 9}$ we have $ \frac{14}{n^2-9} < \frac{\varepsilon}2$.

Therefore for  $n \ge \max\left\{4, 3+\frac6\varepsilon, \sqrt{\frac{28}\varepsilon + 9}\right\}$ we have

\begin{align}
\left|\frac{2n^2-3n+5}{9-n^2}+2\right| &= \frac{|23-3n|}{|9-n^2|}\\
&\le \frac{3n+23}{(n+3)(n-3)}\\
&= \frac{3(n+3)+14}{(n+3)(n-3)}\\
&= \frac{3}{n-3} + \frac{14}{n^2-9}\\
&< \frac{\varepsilon}2 + \frac{\varepsilon}2\\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align}